# Jersey @InjectParam creating a new Object instead of taking from Spring

Tags: java, spring, jersey

I have a Jersey Application using Spring
I am using the **@InjectParam** in the hope (and what is written in the documentation) that Jersey would obtain the object from the Spring Container, but it seems Jersey is creating the object instead of asking Spring for it.

Is there a way of checking if the Spring IOC is registered with Jersey ?

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:appContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My class provide basic access to the factory but the factory is new

```
public FileStoreService(@InjectParam("dataAccessFactory") factory ) {  
   this.factory = factory;    
}
```

and  i have added the **@Component** and still nothing.

Comment: I think the file "appContext.xml" is helpful to show. Additionally it would be interesting to see how you obtain the FileStoreService, I think spring only should inject if you create it via spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrong servlet was being used. It should be

```
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
```

The current one uses Jersey own container, which will only create objects using the default constructer. The Spring Servlet allows Jersey to attached to the Spring Container.